# Why can't I play Roblox on its website?

Tags: roblox

I want to try Roblox, so I got an account and try to play on [www.roblox.com](http://www.roblox.com) .However, it forced me to download Roblox app.

However, after I downloaded Roblox, it still won't let me play. I don't like to play on the app as it is quite laggy.

Is there a way for me to play on the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no possible way to play roblox on the website, The games are connected to roblox servers and the servers are connected to the application. The games are created with Lua not HTML5 so that is another thing that makes you unable to play roblox on the website.
The app may be laggy at some points if you are running heavy and big roblox games on a decent PC. Another factor of lag includes Internet connection. Roblox requires a minimum of 4-8 Mb/s internet connection.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used to play on ipad, the app works just as fine. However, when I switch to pc, the game became so laggy (I used the same wifi)

Comment: It's probably connected to your PC I guess... I've played Roblox since 2018 and I don't have any trouble...